# Recursive synchronization

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, winapi

In my app two threads invoke the same recursive function, that should output data to some file. I don't know how I can synchonized this threads to output correct data. I try a few variants with mutex (commented in code using /**** n ****/), but it doesn't work (output data are mixed from different threads). How can I organize synchronizathion(i should use only WinAPI and std). Pseudocode below:

```
HANDLE hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL,FALSE, 0);
wchar_t** HelpFunction(wchar_t const* p, int *t)
{
    do
    {
        /**** 1 ****/ //WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE);
        wchar_t* otherP= someFunction();
        if(...)
        {
            /**** 2 ****/ //WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE);
            //File's output should be here
            //Outputing p
            /**** 2 ****/ //ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
        }
        if(...)
        {
            HelpFunction(otherP, t);
        }
        /**** 1 ****/ //ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
    }while(...);
}
unsigned int WINAPI ThreadFunction( void* p)
{
    int t = 0;
    /**** 3 ****/ //WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE);
    wchar_t** res = HelpFunction((wchar_t *)p, &t);
    /**** 3 ****/ //ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
    return 0;
}
void _tmain()
{
    HANDLE hThreads[2];
    hThreads[0] = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, ThreadFunction, L"param1", 0, NULL);
    hThreads[1] = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, ThreadFunction, L"param2", 0, NULL);
    WaitForMultipleObjects(2, hThreads, TRUE, INFINITE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With Windows API, if it is a single process, you are probably better off using a Critical Section.

There is no need for a WaitForSingleObject on the critical section, you only use that when you are waiting for some data to write if that is going to happen.

And what I guess you are synchronising is the file-write so each thread writes one whole record at a time. (Ensure you flush any buffers).

You will call

`EnterCriticalSection`

when you get to the sensitive part and

`LeaveCriticalSection`

at the end of the sensitive part.

and look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682608%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the more details API.

The recursion doesn't matter here as long as you are not holding the "lock" at the point you recurse, i.e. you do not recurse from within your critical section code. When you recurse as with the code shown, it will NOT spawn a new thread. I don't know if you were expecting it to.

I cannot actually see any file I/O in your HelpFunction. I do however see the pointer that you just called t. It is the same pointer for both threads and it is non-const. Therefore if both threads are going to be writing to that int, you may need to synchronise that too. Once again your code does not actually show how that pointer is being used.

Comment: Ye, It's single process but i'm afraiding that i'll get the same result. Output data will be mixed from different threads

Comment: I'm knowing a little about CRITICAL_SECTION, Mutex should also work .But there is recursion in my case. And outpt is mixed? I don't know what I  can do?

Comment: Yes, if two threads write to the same output file, you will get output from different threads. The important thing is to ensure that a single "record" appears unbroken. You therefore "lock" during record-writes.

Comment: Ye, but I get <file path="C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Google <file path="D:\ANDRUSko_sait\Orders_2.gif"
 size="8671" /> in some case, but expected <file path="C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Googlesize="8671" /><file path="D:\ANDRUSko_sait\Orders_2.gif"
 size="8671" /> I've tried CRITICAL_SECTION and Mutex but the same result

Comment: @Vsevywniy Flush the output before leaving the critical section. For a FILE*, I seem to recall that the function is called fflush. BTW, you tagged this as C++, but the code looks like C. For example, use a scoped lock. Google RAII.

Comment: @Jive Dadson I've tried even open() and close() functions for file  inside sensitive section but it hasn't helped.

Comment: @Vsevywniy Well then, you are going to need to post a stripped down program that will compile and run, and which includes the writing part.

Comment: Personally I'd just post the data to a log queue and have a separate thread responsible for dumping the messages serially into the output file, thereby leaving all the output IO entirely off the recursion threads. Of course, I'm just lazy that way.

Comment: @WhozCraig No completely understend in what way?

Comment: @WhozCraig - that is not laziness, it's performance enhancement.  A lock around a producer-consumer queue push is going to be much, much faster than a lock around a file operation, especially with a network file with its large latency.  Your solution solves the concurrency issue, has much better performance, is more flexible and is much safer - if a network disk stuffs, some lost logs and an eventual error message from the writer thread 'disk no longer reachable' is much better than the whole app seizing up for minutes.

Comment: @Vsevywniy I asked for a *stripped down* program. No one is going to read through all that formatting and whatnot. You need to read up on C++. All those pointers and malloc calls are what C++ was designed to remove the need for.

Comment: Actually when I did something similar in production a few years ago I did it the way @WhozCraig suggested. Messages to be logged we sent to a queue, and a thread pulled off these messages and wrote them to the file.

Far more efficient as you don't have to keep flushing, the file I/O isn't holding up the process, given you have to lock anyway to write, so doing so to a memory collection is no more expensive on that regard.

Comment: @Martin its funny you mention that, guys. I implemented it with *two* queues (A,B), held inside a logger (L). At any given time L.A or L.B was the "active" queue for users, while the other was being dumped. The log thread would, on condition-set, lock L momentarily to set L.qptr to the empty queue, then releases the lock and proceed to dump the non-empty queue with content to disk. The actual log users (the threads) had no knowledge they were swapping target queues. The time spent under exclusive lock by the writer was literally almost none. I can't tell you how many apps i've use this in now.